# LineNumberReader setLineNumber not working

Tags: java, android

i use LineNumberReader to read text file , when call setLineNumber and getLinenumber it print == 0   But when call readLine again  ์Nit thing happen   how can i fix it
Here is my code

```
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("text.txt"));
    writer.write("This is a line1\n" +
            "This is a line2\n" +
            "This is a line3");
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
    File myFile = new File("text.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);

    // Read from the FileReader.
    String lineRead = "";
    while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(lineRead);
    }

    // Determine the number of lines that were read.
    System.out.println("Total lines read: " +
            reader.getLineNumber());

    // Reset the number of lines read.
    reader.setLineNumber(0);
    System.out.println("Total lines read after reset: " +
            reader.getLineNumber());

    String lineRead2 = "";
    while ((lineRead2 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(lineRead2);
    }
    System.out.println("End");
    // Close the LineNumberReader and FileReader.
    fileReader.close();
    reader.close();
```

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just setting the `LineNumberReader`'s line number counter, not the position in the underlying stream. See the documentation for [Java's LineNumberReader class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html).

You have already processed your stream, and thus a subsequent call to `readLine()` returns null.

If you want to reread the stream, you're going to have to call `fileReader.reset()`, or `reader.reset()`, which will result in your `LineNumberReader` calling the reset for your `FileReader`.

Comment: You can use the "mark()" method on your reader, when you are on the desired line. This causes a subsequent call to "reset()" to reposition the underlying stream to the position, where "mark()" was last called.